# How to get kubernetes secret data from java

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8, java-client

By following link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/ it is described how to add secret (encripted) data.

How to get that key-value s with from java client?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the official Java client for Kubernetes’ REST API and read the secret as defined in this [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#readNamespacedSecret). You will get a result of return type [V1Secret](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1Secret.md).

`V1Secret result = apiInstance.readNamespacedSecret(name, namespace, pretty, exact, export)`;

This object `result` has a property `data` of type `Map<String, byte>` to get the key value pairs from.

Comment: Thank you dear @Javatar81 ,and can I write key-value s from java?

Comment: You could use Patch as described here https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#patchNamespacedSecret

Comment: Nice! And a last question,where I must put my kube host:port,for connectiing?  by calling ApiClient.setBasePath?

Comment: In case anyone was wondering like I was, the class being used is CoreV1Api. readNamespacedSecret